# Bundler:Gemfile not found preventing elastic beanstalk deployment

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I am trying to deploy to elastic beanstalk and I am getting an error that doesn't make a lot of sense to me. Below is the error in my log files, which it is complaining about a missing gemfile; however, the gemfile is indeed there:

```
2014-08-27 13:45:33,639 [INFO] (708 MainThread) [directoryHooksExecutor.py-29] [root directoryHooksExecutor info] Script succeeded.
2014-08-27 13:45:33,639 [INFO] (708 MainThread) [directoryHooksExecutor.py-29] [root directoryHooksExecutor info] Executing script: /opt/elasticbeanstalk/hooks/appdeploy/pre/11_asset_compilation.sh
2014-08-27 13:45:33,675 [INFO] (708 MainThread) [directoryHooksExecutor.py-29] [root directoryHooksExecutor info] Output from script: Skipping asset compilation (RAILS_SKIP_ASSET_COMPILATION=true).

2014-08-27 13:45:33,676 [INFO] (708 MainThread) [directoryHooksExecutor.py-29] [root directoryHooksExecutor info] Script succeeded.
2014-08-27 13:45:33,676 [INFO] (708 MainThread) [directoryHooksExecutor.py-29] [root directoryHooksExecutor info] Executing script: /opt/elasticbeanstalk/hooks/appdeploy/pre/12_db_migration.sh
2014-08-27 13:45:33,711 [INFO] (708 MainThread) [directoryHooksExecutor.py-29] [root directoryHooksExecutor info] Output from script: Skipping database migrations (RAILS_SKIP_MIGRATIONS=true).

2014-08-27 13:45:33,712 [INFO] (708 MainThread) [directoryHooksExecutor.py-29] [root directoryHooksExecutor info] Script succeeded.
2014-08-27 13:45:33,712 [INFO] (708 MainThread) [directoryHooksExecutor.py-29] [root directoryHooksExecutor info] Executing script: /opt/elasticbeanstalk/hooks/appdeploy/pre/13_test_for_puma.rb
2014-08-27 13:45:33,766 [INFO] (708 MainThread) [directoryHooksExecutor.py-29] [root directoryHooksExecutor info] Output from script: /opt/rubies/ruby-2.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler/shared_helpers.rb:22:in `default_gemfile': Could not locate Gemfile (Bundler::GemfileNotFound)
    from /opt/rubies/ruby-2.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler.rb:231:in `default_gemfile'
    from /opt/rubies/ruby-2.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler.rb:177:in `root'
    from /opt/rubies/ruby-2.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler.rb:99:in `bundle_path'
    from /opt/rubies/ruby-2.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler.rb:378:in `configure_gem_home'
    from /opt/rubies/ruby-2.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler.rb:367:in `configure_gem_home_and_path'
    from /opt/rubies/ruby-2.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler.rb:90:in `configure'
    from /opt/rubies/ruby-2.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler.rb:146:in `definition'
    from /opt/elasticbeanstalk/hooks/appdeploy/pre/13_test_for_puma.rb:5:in `<main>'

2014-08-27 13:45:33,766 [ERROR] (708 MainThread) [directoryHooksExecutor.py-33] [root directoryHooksExecutor error] Script /opt/elasticbeanstalk/hooks/appdeploy/pre/13_test_for_puma.rb failed with returncode 1
```

Comment: Does your app have a Gemfile? Can you try creating an empty Gemfile in your app and see if it succeeds?

Comment: Gemfile wasn't the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was a result of me being on Mac OSX Yosemite. When compressing with Yosemite it uses the Darwin binary zip file which elastic beanstalk doesn't support. Try downloading Keka and zipping it with that tool.